# WPF DocumentViewer - Print with no confirmation

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, documentviewer

I have a WPF application where I use a document viewer. I also start printing programmatically with documentviewer.Print(); However, when that is pressed it brings up the screen with the Windows printers and makes the user have to click "OK" again on that screen to start. Is there a way to avoid the confirmation and make documentviewer.Print(); immediately start the print job on the default Windows printer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need is the default print queue, which you can get via

```
var pq = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue()
```

From this, you can create an [XpsDocumentWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552916.aspx):

```
var writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(pq);
```

Now, you can get the [DocumentPaginator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.documentpaginator.aspx) from your DocumentViewer via the [Document property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.documentviewerbase.document.aspx), which returns an IDocumentPaginatorSource that has a [DocumentPaginator property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.idocumentpaginatorsource.documentpaginator.aspx):

```
var paginator = documentviewer.Document.DocumentPaginator;
```

and you can send that right to the [XpsDocumentWriter's Write method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604605.aspx):

```
writer.Write(paginator);
```

Simple, isn't it?

Comment: WOW! Yes, it really is simple, much less so than I had anticipated. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JimBeam: (I was being sarcastic about the "simple" bit)